# Java References over Pointers

Tags: java

Why do java use References for its internal structure, and why java do not prefer pointers.
Is there any big logic behind this ?
Are Pointers not good for addressing or it is not a good way to provide direct address(access) from pointers?

Comment: Because of the garbage collector.

Comment: Is reference not a pointer? Of course you don't get to work with them directly, but it works that way.

Answer (score 1):

A reference *is* a pointer. The real difference is that in Java you can't do pointer *arithmetic*; that is, you can't make pointers to arbitrary memory locations, or add one to a pointer, or the like.

The Java security model depends critically on ensuring that you can't get access to areas of memory that you're not supposed to get access to, either to read protected things, or to change things that shouldn't be changed. If you could do those things, you could manipulate the state of the virtual machine, and break the security model.

But with pointer arithmetic, it would be impossible to keep those protections in place; so they're simply banned in Java.

It's not just security, though: it's also there to protect you. Bugs with pointers can be very subtle and hard to unpick. The Java language is designed to help you write correct code, or at least to write code that doesn't fail in unexpected and unpredictable ways.

Java makes a big thing of trying to avoid undefined behaviour. Pointer arithmetic is a quick route to undefined behaviour in lots of unhappy ways.

Like most things in language design, it's a trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do java use References for its internal structure, and why java do not prefer pointers.

Java uses managed memory which assumes every reference points to a valid Object.  If you pay with pointers you can point anywhere, or nowhere which is not only the cause of many bugs, it make automatic memory management much harder.

> Are Pointers not good for addressing or it is not a good way to provide direct address(access) from pointers?

Yes, but Pointers are very sharp tool.  You can also easily misuse them or introduce bugs.